# Как запускать параллельно выполняющиеся процессы в python c помощью asyncio или других библиотек?

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

Я хочу реализовать выполнение двух бесконечных процессов параллельно с помощью Asyncio. Я попробовал следующее:

```
import asyncio

async def f1():
    print("First function...")
    while True:
        pass

async def f2():
    print("Second function...")
    while True:
        pass


ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    ioloop.create_task(f1()),
    ioloop.create_task(f2())
]
ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
ioloop.close()
```

Программа выводит только:

```
First function
```

А нужно чтобы:

```
First function...
Second function...
```

Как такое реализовать?

**Дополнение:**
Скорее всего мой вопрос был некорректным вместо `pass` я имел в виду определенное действие а не ожидание. Думаю так будет понятнее:

```
import asyncio

async def f1():
    print("Starting first function")
    while True: #Этот код работает бесконечно
        print('First code is working...') 

async def f2():
    print("Starting second function")
    while True: #Этот код тоже работает бесконечно, но не мешает первому
        print('Second code is working too...') 


ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    ioloop.create_task(f1()),
    ioloop.create_task(f2())
]
ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
ioloop.close()
```

Будет выводить:

```
First code is working...
First code is working...
First code is working...
(До бесконечности)
```

А надо что-то на подобии:

```
First code is working...
Second code is working too...
First code is working...
Second code is working too...
(До бесконечности)
```

Возможно я не очень понял суть библиотеки asyncio (Возможно лучше использовать multiprocessing или что-то ещё)

Comment: Какие реальные задачи будут выполнять функции?

Comment: Вообще это для telegram-бота. Одна функция будет ждать сообщения и отправлять ответ, а вторая - отправлять сообщение в конкретное время.

Comment: Документацию [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) просматривали?

Comment: У меня бот на pyTelegramBotAPI. Но документацию посмотрел

Comment: Извините. Я нашел решение для своей задачи. (Хотя все равно хотелось бы понять можно ли сделать так как я описал)

Comment: Ну можно добавить `await asyncio.sleep(x)` в цикл.

Comment: поскольку в примере внутри циклов нет await, то и переключиться на другую задачу и "дать другим поработать" он не может.

Comment: @vitidev Получается с помощью asyncio такую задачу нельзя решить?

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Из примеров не видно. А вообще await означает "я запустил что-то неблокирующее и сам блокировать не буду, подожду тут результата и дам другим поработать". Если у вас есть такой неблокирующий код (это ввод-вывод- запись в файл, работа с сетью..), то на них и можно переключить задачи. Если же неблокирующего ничего нет, то и переключения не будет - тогда придется использовать костыль await asyncio.sleep или же городить кооперативную многозадачность через генераторы.

Comment: Вообще если у вас блокирующий код, но очень хочется использовать async/await, то посмотрите реализацию aiofiles - он как раз такое делает. Я подозреваю, что в asyncio все так делается - все перемалывается через пул потоков, а async/await предоставляет удобную работу.

Comment: @vitidev Понял. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Возможно я не очень понял суть библиотеки asyncio (Возможно лучше использовать multiprocessing или что-то ещё)`
Все зависит от вашей задачи, Ваш пример, не работает параллельно, потому что в функциях выполняются блокирующие операции.

Ядро асинхронного приложения - это событийный цикл. В вашем примере, не вдаваясь в детали, `ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` - вы его получаете,
`tasks = [ ioloop.create_task(f1()), ioloop.create_task(f2()) ]` - создаете задачи для него, `ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))` запускаете эти задачи внутри него. Цикл событий выполняет только одну задачу, до тех пор пока не встречает неблокирующую операцию, когда задача `Task` выполняется с оператором `await`, то выполняющаяся задача приостанавливается, а цикл обработки событий выполняет следующую задачу. Для вашего примера достаточно добавить `asyncio.sleep(0.1)` что бы цикл событий мог передавать контекст выполнения между задачами.

```
import asyncio

async def f1():
    print("First function...")
    while True:  # Этот код работает бесконечно
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) #-> на этом месте цикл событий переключит выполнение на другую задачу
        print('First code is working...')

async def f2():
    print("Second function...")
    while True:  # Этот код тоже работает бесконечно, но не мешает первому
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)#-> на этом месте цикл событий переключит выполнение на другую задачу
        print('Second code is working too...')


ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    ioloop.create_task(f1()),
    ioloop.create_task(f2())
]
ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
ioloop.close()
```

Если Вы не используете асинхронные библиотеки в задачах, или другие i/o wait операции ( к примеру открытий файла и чтение из него, тут можно было использовать потоки), а распаралеливание затрагивает только cpu операции, то необходимо использовать процессы `multiprocessing`. Как пример:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def f1():
    print("First function...")
    while True:  # Этот код работает бесконечно
        print('First code is working...')
        time.sleep(0.1)

def f2():
    print("Second function...")
    while True:  # Этот код тоже работает бесконечно, но не мешает первому
        print('Second code is working too...')
        time.sleep(0.1) # это не обязательно

def main(func: callable):
    func()

tasks = [f1, f2]
procs = [mp.Process(target=main, args=(i,)) for i in tasks] # создаем столько процессов, сколько имеем функций
for proc in procs:
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

На практике чаще имеется одна функция и много аргументов, и необходимость распаралелить выполнение одной функции. Тогда кол-во аргументов бьется на пачки и передается пачка в каждый процесс, если кол-во процессов < "пачек" то лучше использовать пул процессов (`multiprocessing.Pool`), так как создание процесса считается тяжелой операцией, а так у Вас заранее будет выделено N процессов в вашем пуле.

Comment: await asyncio.sleep(0) можно - тогда будет работать без задержки. и не забывайте про экзекуторы - они удобнее поднятия треда вручную

Comment: А, понял. Спасибо вам огромное.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio


async def f1():
    print("First function...")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(4)


async def f2():
    print("Second function...")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(4)


ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    ioloop.create_task(f1()),
    ioloop.create_task(f2())
]
ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
ioloop.close()
```

в новых версиях питон **Python (≥ 3.7)** лучше запускать асинхронные функции так:

```
async def f1():
    print("First function...")
    await asyncio.sleep(4) # Имитирование работы программы
    print(f'{f1.__name__} Done')


async def f2():
    print("Second function...")
    await asyncio.sleep(4) # Имитирование работы программы
    print(f'{f2.__name__} Done')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`pass` блокирующая команда, вместо нее лучше использовать `asyncio.sleep` как имитирование работы функции. Для одновременного выполнения асинхронных программ нужно добавить их в `asyncio.gather(func(), func()...)` а затем запустить с помощью `asyncio.run`

Comment: Наверное я не правильно объяснил суть вопроса. Я дополнил его

Comment: лучше запускать асинхронные функции так - не лучше. для задачи в 2 таска наоборот хуже)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял из слов [**@vitdev**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191496) (спасибо ему огромное) с помощью **asincio** параллельно можно запустить *"только неблокирующий код (это ввод-вывод- запись в файл, работа с сетью..)"*. Поэтому asincio подойдёт не для любых задач.

**P.S** [@asanisimov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361713/asanisimov) объяснил как работает Этот модуль. Всетаки asincio может помочь, просто работает по другому принципу. Спасибо большое [@asanisimov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361713/asanisimov)

Я нашел решение данного вопроса с помощью модуля **threading**. Например так:

```py
from threading import Thread

def f1():
    print("Starting first function")
    while True: #Этот код работает бесконечно
        print('First code is working...')

def f2():
    print("Starting second function")
    while True: #Этот код тоже работает бесконечно
        print('Second code is working too...')



class MyThread(Thread):
    """A threading example"""
    
    def __init__(self, name, function): # name - некое имя потока (Можно было и без этого обойтись)
                                        # function - функция, которая будет запущена параллельно основному потоку
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.function = function
    
    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        self.function()

    
def create_threads():
    """Создаем группу потоков"""
    
    name = "Thread 1"
    function = f1
    my_thread1 = MyThread(name, function)
    my_thread1.start()

    name = "Thread 2"
    function = f2
    my_thread2 = MyThread(name, function)
    my_thread2.start()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

Вывод у этой программы довольно страшный (Не буду вставлять), но это значит что все работает.

Можно заменить `print('First code is working...')` и `print('Second code is working too...')` на `pass` и убедиться, что обе функции запустились:

```py
from threading import Thread

def f1():
    print("Starting first function")
    while True: #Этот код работает бесконечно
        pass

def f2():
    print("Starting second function")
    while True: #Этот код тоже работает бесконечно
        pass



class MyThread(Thread):
    """A threading example"""
    
    def __init__(self, name, function): # name - некое имя потока
                                        # function - функция, которая будет запущена параллельно основному потоку
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.function = function
    
    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        self.function()

    
def create_threads():
    """Создаем группу потоков"""
    
    name = "Thread 1"
    function = f1
    my_thread1 = MyThread(name, function)
    my_thread1.start()

    name = "Thread 2"
    function = f2
    my_thread2 = MyThread(name, function)
    my_thread2.start()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

Вывод:

```
Starting first function
Starting second function
```

Answer (score 0):

Если функция асинхронная

```
async def f1():
    print("Async function...")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Если функция синхронная

```
async def f2():
    print("Blocking function...")
    while True:
        await ioloop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep(5))
```

Если на функции не блокирующий опрос состояния можно сделать так - `await asyncio.sleep(0)` выполняется на каждом шаге лупа пока другой таск висит на слове await в конкурентном таске

```
async def f2():
    print("Check function...")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        if driver.state == 1:
            ioloop.call_soon(cb)
```

await asyncio.sleep(0) можно использовать как переключатель между тасками если не беда что они будут блокироваться - например при какой-нибудь математике, когда ещё не выгодно уходить на мультипроцессинг.

Тут колбэк может снова заблокировать луп - так что смотрим выше